# How to sort an array by substring, perl

Tags: perl, sorting, substring

So, for example i have array like that:

```
my @arr = (
"blabla\t23\t55",
"jkdcbx\t55\t89",
"jdxjcl\t88\t69",
......)
```

And i need to sort this array by second column after \t, without outer splits. Is it possible to do?

Comment: *"without outer splits"* What do you mean by that?

Comment: *"sort this array by second column after \t"* Do you mean the third column?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be a more elegant way but this will work :

```
my @arr = ( "blabla\t23\t55", "jkdcbx\t55\t89", "jdxjcl\t88\t69");
for (sort {(split(/\t/,$a))[2] <=> (split(/\t/,$b))[2]} @arr) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Your code is elegant, but I was curious if there was a faster way to sort, as it seems like you run the split code more than is needed. The following code on a big data set takes 8 seconds compared to 19 seconds for your way.

`my %arr_assoc;
my @arr = ( "blabla\t23\t55", "jkdcbx\t55\t89", "jdxjcl\t88\t69");
for (@arr) {$a = (split(/\t/))[2]; $arr_assoc{$_}=$a}
for (sort {$arr_assoc{$a} <=> $arr_assoc{$b}} keys %arr_assoc)
{print "$_\n"}`

Comment: @EricKlien yes much improved, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

I've just realised that your question may mean that you want to sort by the *third* column instead of the second

That would be done by using

```
my ($aa, $bb) = map { (split /\t/)[2] } $a, $b;
```

instead

#### output

```
blabla  23  55
jdxjcl  88  69
jkdcbx  55  89
```

---

I always prefer to use `map` to convert the values from the original data into the function that they should be sorted by

This program demonstrates

I assume you want the values sorted numerically? Unfortunately your example data is already sorted as you describe

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @arr = (
    "blabla\t23\t55",
    "jkdcbx\t55\t89",
    "jdxjcl\t88\t69",
);


my @sorted = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map { (split /\t/)[1] } $a, $b;
    $aa <=> $bb;
} @arr;

say for @sorted;
```

#### output

```
blabla  23  55
jkdcbx  55  89
jdxjcl  88  69
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
use warnings;
use strict;
no warnings "numeric";

my @arr = (
"blabla\t23\t55",
"jkdcbx\t85\t89",
"jdxjcl\t83\t69",
);

my @result = sort {$a=~s/^[^\t]*\t//r <=> $b=~s/^[^\t]*\t//r } @arr;

$, = "\n";

print @result,"\n";
```

I have used following technique with sort for to do it

[Negation character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Negation)

> Non-destructive modifier(-r) -  perform non-destructive substitution and return the new value

And tured of the warning for numeric